# Properties of electric field if it varied as $1/r^3$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnT4i.jpg)
I was asked the above question in my exam and the answer given was that the statement 2 was correct in the context of the given question (statement 1 was obviously wrong as gauss's law cannot be applied in the case) . Here is the question:

If we consider a spherical shell with uniformly distributed charge on its surface what difference does it make or how does it matter how the electric field varies with distance because at any point within the shell the electric field due to an elemental charge residing on the surface of the shell will be cancelled by some other elemental charge on the surface(due to symmetry) making the net field inside to be zero and thus net force on any charge placed inside to also be zero.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of problem. Please don't post questions that require clicking through to a link in order to find out what the question really is. Please don't post questions as screenshots of text; this breaks search functionality and doesn't work for blind users. Please don't cut and paste things other people wrote on the internet without attribution -- it's rude. I don't think we should even be discussing your exam questions here.

Comment: Well I had a genuine question related to the concept and instead of typing the whole thing out I just posted the link of the related question and went on to elaborate on that.I just don't get the fact that the response to the question that you have asked is based on the way you articulate it.

Comment: You can reduce the dimensions of your problem to understand it better. Imagine a normal (inverse squares) 3D charge inside a charged 2D ring. (1) Does all the flux of the charge go through the ring? (Does the ring always block you from seeing the charge?) (2) Will the charge be pulled to one side of the ring?

Answer (score 3):

> at any point within the shell the electric field due to an elemental charge residing on the surface of the shell will be cancelled by some other elemental charge on the surface

No. For an *arbitrary* point inside, this cancellation only happens when the force is inverse square. You can’t just argue “There’s charge on the opposite side, so the force cancels out.” That symmetry argument works *only at the center*. For other points inside, you have to do an actual *calculation* that takes into account the *size* of the opposite area elements (because $dq=\sigma dA$) and their varying *distances* from the point inside at which you are trying to calculate the field.

Comment: Can you show mathematically that it happens?

Comment: That *what* happens? That the field inside doesn’t vanish if the field of a point charge isn’t inverse square?

Comment: Yes exactly could you do that?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to compute the potential inside the sphere and show that it isn’t constant. If the field of a point charge varies as $1/r^n$ then the potential of a point charge varies as $1/r^{n-1}$. The potential at a point $\vec{r}$ inside a spherical shell of charge is then proportional to the integral of $dq/|\vec{r}-\vec{r}’|^{n-1}$ where $\vec{r}’$ ranges over the spherical shell. You can evaluate this integral using spherical polar coordinates and show that when $n=2$ it is a constant but otherwise is a function of $r$.

Comment: I’m not going to actually do the integral because this is a common homework problem.

Comment: Oh ok I get it now thanks.